# Range, empty row in Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've found a snippet for selecting the next empty row in excel, but when I run the macro it tells me that it throws a runtime error 1004. Any idea why?

```
Sub CopyValues()

Sheets("Report").Select
Range("B4:D10").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

And yes, the worksheet names are correct.
    `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select` throws the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CopyValues()
    Sheets("Report").Range("B4:D10").Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: But I've noticed now that it always copys the data on the same cell. Any idea why? It seems "not" to find the next empty row

Comment: Nope- Down was correct. Up just works as intended if i start bottom up

Comment: @Michael well you should have mentioned that in your question that you're starting from bottom up hehe

Comment: I'm not. I wanted to start top down